# permanent link to latest anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

There is a link to the latest miniconda that always points to the latest version: https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

But I could not find a similar link to the latest anaconda. Is there a way to obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no similar link for Anaconda.

I've got a setup script I like to run on new machines that installs Anaconda. While I occasionally update the link, my strategy for ensuring the latest version of conda is to install and then update conda. For example:

```
# Install Anaconda
if [ -x "$(command -v conda)" ]; then
  echo 'Anaconda is already installed!'
else
  curl -L https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh > anaconda_script.sh
  bash anaconda_script.sh -b
  rm anaconda_script.sh
fi
conda update --yes conda
conda update --yes anaconda
source ~/.bash_profile
```

As long as the python version of the anaconda that you want is the same there should be no issues updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the website's html page to find out what is the current latest version available for download:

```
wget -O - https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ 2>/dev/null | sed -ne 's@.*\(https:\/\/repo\.anaconda\.com\/archive\/Anaconda3-.*-Linux-x86_64\.sh\)\">64-Bit (x86) Installer.*@\1@p'
```

This gives me as an output:
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh